# content inside extended div outside of parent div not showing in mobile

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm using the following CSS to allow my content on a wordpress page to extend outside of the parent div. It worked great except when I view the website on a mobile device. The content is not adjusting according to the size of the browser. Any advice on fixing this issue?

```css
.extended-content-container {
 width: 500%;
 margin-left: -200%;
 padding-top: 0;
 padding-bottom: 60px;
 background-color: #333;
}

.extended-content {
 width: 100%;
 height: 300px;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="extended-content-container">
<div class="extended-content">
<span style="color: #ffffff;"><span style="color: #ffffff;">
</span></span>
<h2><span style="color: #fff;">HELLO THERE.</span></h2>
<span style="color: #fff;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use

```
width: 500%;
margin-left: -200%;
```

to do that. Since you do use it, the content is doing exactly what you told it to do, be 5 times wider and go to the left in width of two times itself.

If you would insist on using those declarations on desktop, than use @media queries and set

```
width: 100%;
margin-left: 0;
```

**UPDATE**

When you have full-width parent element with padding and child element that has to be full width, and you can't use position absolute on child, than this is the one of the solutions;

Move child left, and increase child width, with following formula, assuming **x** is the sum of parent element left and right padding percentage

$child-width-in-percentage = 100 + (**x** / (100 - **x**) * 100)

$child-left-margin-in-percentage = **x** / (100 - **x**) * 100 / -2

So, in example of parent div

```
.single-themes-page {
    padding: 0 10%;
}
```

child gets following style:

```
.extended-content-container {
    width: 125%;
    margin-left: -12.5%;
}
```

If you have different parent padding percentage values in @media queries, change child (.extended-content-container) width and margin-left values per above formula in those @media rules.

This way you will have fully responsive browser window full width child.

Comment: I tried using that... however when I use @media only screen and adjus the width and margin-left accordingly, it removes extending the .extended-content-container. The reason I have the width and margin-left set at 500% and -200% is the extend the div beyond the parent div (which I can't control since this is in WP). Any other suggestions?

Comment: More context would be appreciated. Parent you are referring to is parent of .extended-content-container? More info on that parent? Maybe there is a way to control parent, being WP generated doesn't necessarily have to mean it is not controllable. Context would help.

Comment: If you minimize the browser or view the site on a mobile device, you'll see that the content does not adjust with the screen size.

Comment: So I added @media screen {

Comment: I added @media screen{ .extended-content-container{width: 125%; margin-left: -12.5%;}} in addition to the ,extended-content-container and .extended-content but the text still is not responsive. Did I do this correctly?

Comment: See https://developer.chrome.com/devtools to understand how to use DevTools to see what is going on with your website and css on different browser sizes.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp to understand responsive web design and breakpoints (ignore Always Design for Mobile First section).

Comment: Delete your width: 500%; margin-left: -200%; and replace with values you put in @media query.

Comment: While in DevTools find . single-themes-page and track how its padding changes on different breakpoints, then use approriate media queries to adjust the width and margin-left as per above formula for different breakpoints. Only then you will see changes.

Comment: Understanding @media queries/breakpoints and using DevTools is must to accomlish what you need.

Comment: If you do that you will se there is a rule media screen and (min-width: 38.75em) { .single-themes-page{padding:0 9.0909%} }. So your x would be 18.1818, make calculations and put this in your css "@media screen and (min-width: 38.75em) { .extended-content-container{ calculated declarations here } }". Do this for every media rule where you see different values for .single-themes-page

Comment: And actually dont ignore Always Design for Mobile First section, because your website is mobile first